# Can i import a blender animated tree to unity3d and make sure the tree keeps being animated?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, blender

Hello everyone I wanted to ask if I can import my animated tree from Blender to Unity if so how would I do it? Also I wanted to ask how would I make my tree do the animated over and over. So pretty much the tree waves a bit and leaves fall just want to know how to make it keep doing it over and over.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitley possible if you export the model correctly 
although I've never heard of this effect in a .blend file so 
I assume you will need to export in a specific model format 
You may attempt to export in .blend 
it may work and it won't hurt to try 
If it does not continue to animate (which it should)
Then you will need to export in a different format such as .md5 or .obj or .mm3D 
or if your a good programmer or have a prgram buddy 
then to can make your own export script for blender 
and import script for unity :)
Hope this helps ,I apologize if it does not, and good luck :)